# multiple maps with varying latlang depending upon class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have 9 maps within one page. I currently have nine functions and nine click events. this seemed far too bloated so I am trying to make my code more dynamic. In this process i have hit a brick wall. I have written some code, that in principle, should work. But reasons unknown to me, it will not load the maps

DEMO with nine functions and 9 click events http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2074/

DEMO trying to optimize http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2076/

```
function mapOneInitialize() {
    var mapId = $(this).attr('id');
    var map;
    if ($(mapId).hasClass("partnerName1")) {
        var thisLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142);
    } else if ($(mapId).hasClass("partnerName2")) {
        var thisLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142);
    } else if ($(mapId).hasClass("partnerName3")) {
        var thisLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142);
    } else if ($(mapId).hasClass("partnerName4")) {
        var thisLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142);
    } else if ($(mapId).hasClass("partnerName5")) {
        var thisLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142);
    } else if ($(mapId).hasClass("partnerName6")) {
        var thisLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142);
    } else if ($(mapId).hasClass("partnerName7")) {
        var thisLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142);
    } else if ($(mapId).hasClass("partnerName8")) {
        var thisLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142);
    } else if ($(mapId).hasClass("partnerName9")) {
        var thisLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142);
    }
    var centerPosition = thisLatLang;

    var options = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: centerPosition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($(mapId)[0], options);
};

$('.map').click(function () {
    mapOneInitialize();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

First, `var mapId = $(this).attr('id');` isn't picking up the id of the map. To correct this you should pass `this` through to the `mapOneInitialize` function like so:

```
$('.map').click(function () {
  mapOneInitialize(this);
});

function mapOneInitialize(el) {
  var mapId = $(el).attr('id');
...
```

Second, your jQuery selectors using the mapId are incorrect. They should be changed to `$('#' + mapId)`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/x8dSP/2083/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems that the boxes load only a grey background, rather than the map, other than the first box, i'm not sure why?

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? If you click on the first box the map appears.

Comment: I checked the fiddle, the first box is fine but the other boxes are grey. I'm using chrome. I think it's something simple but not sure what.

Comment: I didn't bother to change all the selectors. Just the one for the first map.

Comment: i need more coffee, how did i miss that. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have to make the map variable a global array and add 3 custom data attribute `data-no,data-lat,data-long` for easy access for the div.

```
 var map = [];
```

and in html

```
<div id="map" class="map map1" data-no="1"></div>
```

I have updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2089/)

Comment: Thanks, this seems better than my approach with the multiple `if` statements  +1